# Naming convention of im2bw in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, naming-conventions

What does `w` mean in `im2bw` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/im2bw.html), `im2bw` converts an image to a 2-valued image.  I'd guess the 2 values represent black and white.  Hence, I'd guess the w is white.